# How to bypass onCompleted

Tags: rx-java

I use BehaviorSubject to make a stream of events from different sources.
Being simplified, It look like that:

```
BehaviorSubject subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
Observable<Integer> src1 = Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
Observable<Integer> src2 = Observable.just(4, 5, 6);
Observable<Integer> src3 = Observable.just(7, 8, 9);
src1.subscribe(subject);
src2.subscribe(subject);
src3.subscribe(subject);
subject.subscribe(this::log);
```

In this example values from `src1` only will be logged, because no more subject subscription will exists after `src1` completion.

How could I bypass completion events from all the sources? Is there an operator like `ignoreCompleted()`?

Comment: Why use a Subject to merge a stream of events when you can simply use the merge operator?

Comment: Because I have many subject's subscribers. I.e. I share stream with many subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it ignores onComplete() and onError(): https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay

Comment: More simple is to wrap subject in Subscription, calling subject.onNext() only (and I suspect this library does it exactly). Anyway, will try it, thank you!